# Problem when specifying build configuration in TFS2010 build definition

Tags: visual-studio-2010, msbuild

Allow me to start by saying that this is a new and first time TFS deployment with 0 experience in Visual Studio as an added bonus. I've managed to get everything installed and am excited to say that I can even deploy as part of the build process to our different staging environments, but this is where things have gone south.

I'm trying to set up separate build definitions for each stage of development so that I can take advantage of config transforms and use granular permissions for who gets to promote where. In the configuration manager I have it set up so each solution configuration has a 1-1 mapping to a project context and always building 'Any CPU'. The problem is that when I use the /p:Configuration=QA switch in the MSBuild Arguments or just specify it in the 'Items to Build; section of the Build process parameters the build fails with a warning and it doesn't seem to get as far as MSDeploy.

Using the following arguments to MSBuild I am deploying with a default configuration, but again, no love on specifying a configuration.

> /p:DeployOnBuild=True /p:DeployTarget=MSDeployPublish /p:MSDeployPublishMethod=WMSVC /p:MsDeployServiceUrl=10.31.60.109 /p:username=tfsdeploy /p:password=lulz /p:DeployIISAppPath=Bob /p:AllowUntrustedCertificate=True

Here is the warning I get in the TFS Build Explorer when specifying the configuration to use.

> C:\Builds\2\Bob\Bob - Final Test\Sources\Bob\Bob.sln.metaproj: The specified solution configuration "QA|Any CPU" is invalid. Please specify a valid solution configuration using the Configuration and Platform properties (e.g. MSBuild.exe Solution.sln /p:Configuration=Debug /p:Platform="Any CPU") or leave those properties blank to use the default solution configuration.

The solution originally was created in VS2008 and a local copy from VSS was pulled down with VS2008 and then pushed into TFS2010 using VS2010 pretty much letting MS work its magic to convert/update.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue I ran into here was that the names of the build configurations were different in the .sln and .csproj files and these can't be mapped to each other as I thought I was doing from within the VS2010 ide.

This is actually a pretty simple error. If you get it, check your spelling in the build definition then verify against the .sln and .csproj files using a text editor like vim/notepad.

Answer (score 0):

Did you get this fixed?  I've noticed some of our builds are "AnyCPU" and others are "Any CPU", makes reports a little more interesting!